Flask App and Flarum Forum Conflict When Running Simultaneously
I'm encountering an issue where my Flask application and my Flarum forum cannot run simultaneously. When my Flask script is running in the background, the Flarum forum stops working. However, when I stop the Flask script, the Flarum forum comes back online.
Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?
Here is portion of my submit.py script for the Flask application:
app_s = Flask(__name__)
app_s.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(24)
app_s.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True
app_s.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = True
csrf = CSRFProtect()
csrf.init_app(app_s)

limiter = Limiter(
    get_remote_address,
    app=app_s,
    default_limits=["35 per day", "12 per hour"]  # Example rate limits
)

@app_s.route('/', methods=['POST'])
@csrf.exempt
def execute():
    try:
        caminho_arquivo_para_upload = bleach.clean(request.form['target_file'])
        nome_pasta = bleach.clean(request.form['folder_name'])
        nome = bleach.clean(request.form['name'])
        email = bleach.clean(request.form['email'])
        logger.info("target_file=%s, folder_name=%s, name=%s, email=%s", caminho_arquivo_para_upload, nome_pasta, nome, email)

        if not caminho_arquivo_para_upload or not nome_pasta or not nome or not email:
            logger.error("Dados em falta: target_file=%s, folder_name=%s, name=%s, email=%s", caminho_arquivo_para_upload, nome_pasta, nome, email)
            return jsonify({'status': 'FALHA', 'erro': 'Dados em falta'}), 400

        if caminho_arquivo_para_upload.startswith('python/'):
            caminho_arquivo_para_upload = caminho_arquivo_para_upload[len('python/'):]

        caminho_absoluto_arquivo = os.path.join(diretorio_atual, caminho_arquivo_para_upload)
        logger.info(f"Caminho absoluto do arquivo recebido: {caminho_absoluto_arquivo}, nome da pasta: {nome_pasta}, nome: {nome}, email: {email}")

        if servico is None:
            enviar_email(nome, email, False)
            remover_da_base_de_dados(nome_pasta)
            return jsonify({'status': 'FALHA', 'erro': 'Serviço não disponível'}), 400

        try:
            scan_result = scan_file_with_virustotal(api_key, caminho_absoluto_arquivo)
            if 'scan_id' in scan_result:
                logger.info("ID do Scan: %s", scan_result['scan_id'])
                logger.info("Resultado do Scan: %s", scan_result['verbose_msg'])

            if 'positives' in scan_result:
                logger.error("Número de positivos: %s", scan_result['positives'])
                logger.info("Caminho do arquivo recebido: %s", caminho_absoluto_arquivo)
                diretorio_uploads = os.path.join(diretorio_atual, 'uploads')
                deletar_arquivo_especifico(diretorio_uploads, caminho_absoluto_arquivo)
                verificar_e_deletar_se_necessario(diretorio_uploads)
                enviar_email(nome, email, True)
                remover_da_base_de_dados(nome_pasta)
                logger.error("O script será encerrado devido à detecção de vírus")
                return jsonify({'status': 'FALHA', 'erro': 'Vírus detectados'}), 400
            else:
                logger.info("Nenhum vírus encontrado: %s", scan_result['verbose_msg'])
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception("Erro durante o processo de escaneamento")
            return jsonify({'status': 'FALHA', 'erro': str(e)}), 400

        try:
            id_pasta = criar_pasta(servico, id_pai, nome_pasta)
            logger.info(f"Pasta criada com ID '{id_pasta}'")
            
            if not os.path.isfile(caminho_absoluto_arquivo):
                raise FileNotFoundError(f"Arquivo não encontrado: {caminho_absoluto_arquivo}")

            fazer_upload_arquivo_drive(servico, caminho_absoluto_arquivo, id_pasta)
            criar_arquivo_texto(nome, email, id_pasta)
            logger.info(f"Arquivos enviados com sucesso para a pasta com ID '{id_pasta}'.")

        except Exception as e:
            enviar_email(nome, email, False)
            remover_da_base_de_dados(nome_pasta)
            logger.exception("Erro durante o processo de upload")
            return jsonify({'status': 'FALHA', 'erro': str(e)}), 400

        logger.info("Caminho do arquivo recebido: %s", caminho_absoluto_arquivo)
        diretorio_uploads = os.path.join(diretorio_atual, 'uploads')
        deletar_arquivo_especifico(diretorio_uploads, caminho_absoluto_arquivo)
        verificar_e_deletar_se_necessario(diretorio_uploads)
        return jsonify({'status': 'SUCESSO'})
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception("Erro ao executar o script")
        return jsonify({'status': 'FALHA', 'erro': str(e)}), 400

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        app_s.run() 
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception("Erro ao iniciar o servidor Flask")
    finally:
        for handler in logger.handlers:
            handler.close()
            logger.removeHandler(handler)

And here is portion the PHP script that calls the Flask application:
function executar_script_python($target_file, $folder_name, $nome, $email) {
    $url = 'https://neei-utad.pt/';
    $data = array(
        'target_file' => $target_file,
        'folder_name' => $folder_name,
        'name' => $nome,
        'email' => $email
    );

    escrever_log("Dados enviados para o script Python: " . json_encode($data));

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ),
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = @file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    if ($result === FALSE) {
        $error = error_get_last();
        escrever_log("Erro ao executar o script Python: " . $error['message']);
        redirecionar_para('../Apontamentos/ConfirmacionFail.html');
    }

    escrever_log("Resposta recebida do script Python: " . $result);

    $response = json_decode($result, true);
    if ($response === null) {
        escrever_log("Erro ao decodificar a resposta JSON do script Python");
        redirecionar_para('../Apontamentos/ConfirmacionFail.html');
    }

    if ($response['status'] === 'SUCESSO') {
        redirecionar_para('../Apontamentos/ConfirmacionSuccesfully.html');
    } else {
        escrever_log("O script Python reportou falha: " . (isset($response['erro']) ? $response['erro'] : 'Erro desconhecido'));
        redirecionar_para('../Apontamentos/ConfirmacionFail.html');
    }
}


When i turn of the script on python selector on cpanel the forum goes bak online...
I don´t even know how to start.
No shared database connections between Flask and Flarum
Enabled detailed logging for both applications but found no clear error messages.
Flarum Error: Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

I move my Flarum Forum to a folder outside of public_html and create subdomain to that folder. And that solves the issue for me.
